# undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError) when running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, authlogic

Hi I've been following a tutorial for **authlogic** gem in railscasts... http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic?view=asciicast

From the tutorial, I was asked to add `config.gem "authlogic"` in my environment.rb

Is it the old way in installing a gem? or the right way to make authlogic work?

I removed the `config.gem "authlogic"` and tried to install the gem using `gem install authlogic` and by putting `gem 'authlogic'` inside my Gemfile (then bundle it)

Authlogic gives automatic form validation (when there's no input or what)

But it is not working. It could be possibly that I didn't install the authlogic gem properly?

What do you think is the problem why my Authlogic gem is not working..

Answer (score 0):

Given the age of the Railscast, it's a good bet that the installation procedure is outdated. Luckily, the [authlogic github page](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) has not only updated install instructions (it is, as you'd expect and predicted, adding `gem 'authlogic'` to your Gemfile), it also has links to assorted tutorials and documentation. Hopefully you can use those to sort out your issue.